# ListView text color change?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-manifest

I know many of you will say just search Google, but if that was that easy I wouldnt ask :).
I have one `ListView` and dynamically I add another list etc.

Now i want to change the text color with XML.

This is my XML:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:textColor="#D0640D" 
        android:fadeScrollbars="true">
</ListView>
```

Can anybody help? :)

Comment: You can't change the text color in the `ListView`. What does your `ListView` contain?

Comment: see this tuts ,,,and you can change row color http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/

Comment: my ListView contains an ArrayAdapter<String> with contains String.

Comment: we can specify textViewResourceId in ArrayAdapter Constructor in that We can specify u r custom textView layout

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the `textColor` attribute of your list item layout, not the list itself. If you are using one of the predefined item layouts, then just copy it into your project and modify it.

Comment: as i said,i dont have list items in my xml.i add them programmatically

Comment: Of course you do, you can't add list items by xml, you need them to be added by an Adapter. Now that adapter uses some kind of layout for each item.

Answer (score 0):

What text are you trying to change the color of? If its of the list items, you need to set the text color of the layout you are using for each of the items in your list.

Comment: how?i dont add them with xml but programmaticaly

Comment: Then call setTextColor on the views that you are adding programmatically.

Comment: in which object?In the Listview,listAdapter or the ArrayList?No one seems to have this method

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InfoWifiActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,networks);
mylistview.setAdapter(listAdapter);

Comment: You need to get the layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` copy it to your layout folder, make your color changes there and then use that for your adapter row layout

Comment: i found this on internet http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml
i made a new xml file in the layout folder and i added this lines android:textColor="#D0640D" android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
no one of them worked

Comment: Did you replace your adapter call with R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead of *ANDROID*.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?